# Pyspark filter operation on Dstream

Tags: pyspark, dstream

I have been trying to extend the network word count to be able to filter lines based on certain keyword

I am using spark 1.6.2

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: network_wordcount.py <hostname> <port>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingNetworkWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

    lines = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).filter("ERROR")
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I have tried all the variations,

> I almost always get the error I cannot apply functions like
>
> pprint/show/take/collect on TransformedDStream

. I used transform with foreachRDD on lines Dstream with a function to check using native python string methods, that fails too (actually if I use print anywhere in the program, spark-submit just comes out - there are no errors reported.

What I want to is to be able to filter the incoming Dstreams on a keyword like "ERROR" | "WARNING" etc and output it to stdout or stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to is to be able to filter the incoming Dstreams on a keyword like "ERROR" | "WARNING" etc and output it to stdout or stderr.

Then you don't want to call `flatMap`, as this will split your lines up into individual tokens. Instead, you can replace that call with a call to `filter` that checks whether the line contains `"error"`:

```
lines = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
errors = lines.filter(lambda l: "error" in l.lower())
errors.pprint()
```

Comment: Thanks @dfernig I have accepted the answer. I thought I was comparing word by word for "ERROR" by split.filter :)

I have a follow up question which I have posted here, if can have a look?

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200620/pyspark-transfer-control-out-of-spark-session-sc)