# Pyspark - Transfer control out of Spark Session (sc)

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, dstream

This is a follow up question on

[Pyspark filter operation on Dstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152236/pyspark-filter-operation-on-dstream?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

To keep a count of how many error messages/warning messages has come through for say a day, hour - how does one design the job.

What I have tried:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


    def counts():
            counter += 1
            print(counter.value)

    if __name__ == "__main__":

            if len(sys.argv) != 3:
                    print("Usage: network_wordcount.py <hostname> <port>", file=sys.stderr)
            exit(-1)


            sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingNetworkWordCount")
            ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
            counter = sc.accumulator(0)

            lines = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
            errors = lines.filter(lambda l: "error" in l.lower())
            errors.foreachRDD(lambda e : e.foreach(counts))
            errors.pprint()

            ssc.start()
            ssc.awaitTermination()
```

this however has multiple issues, to start with print doesn't work (does not output to stdout, I have read about it, the best I can use here is logging). Can I save the output of that function to a text file and tail that file instead?

I am not sure why the program just comes out, there is no error/dump anywhere to look further into (spark 1.6.2)

How does one preserve state? What I am trying is to aggregate logs by server and severity, another use case is to count how many transactions were processed by looking for certain keywords

Pseudo Code for what I want to try:

```
foreachRDD(Dstream):
     if RDD.contains("keyword1 | keyword2 | keyword3"):
     dictionary[keyword] = dictionary.get(keyword,0) + 1 //add the keyword if not present and increase the counter
     print dictionary //or send this dictionary to else where
```

The last part of sending or printing dictionary requires switching out of spark streaming context - Can someone explain the concept please?

Answer (score 0):

> print doesn't work

I would recommend reading the [design patterns section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) of the Spark documentation. I think that roughly what you want is something like this:

```
def _process(iter):
    for item in iter:
        print item

lines = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
errors = lines.filter(lambda l: "error" in l.lower())
errors.foreachRDD(lambda e : e.foreachPartition(_process))
```

This will get your call `print` to work (though it is worth noting that the print statement will execute on the workers and not the drivers, so if you're running this code on a cluster you will only see it on the worker logs).

However, it won't solve your second problem:

> How does one preserve state?

For this, take a look at [updateStateByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#updatestatebykey-operation) and the [related example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/stateful_network_wordcount.py).

Comment: Would it be print item or print(item) - For some reason, when I use "print" anywhere in the program it comes out with out any errors - more like "crash" with out any debugging info/error